# Gtk_entry is NULL

Tags: c, gtk

im using a GSlist to pass 2 GTK_ENTRY to a callback function , but in the callback function when i try to retrieve the data from this 2 GTK_ENTRY , an error message appear , where did i make a mistake ? Is there another way to retrieve a data that a user send in a GTK_ENTRY to a callback function ? Gratefull for help

In the main function :

```
GtkWidget *pEntryID;
GtkWidget *pEntryMDP;
GSList *lLogMdp = NULL;


pEntryID = gtk_entry_new();
gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(pBoiteTotal), pEntryID);
lLogMdp = g_slist_append(lLogMdp,(GtkWidget*) pEntryID);

pEntryMDP = gtk_entry_new();
gtk_entry_set_visibility(GTK_ENTRY(pEntryMDP), FALSE);
gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(pBoiteTotal), pEntryMDP);
lLogMdp = g_slist_append(lLogMdp,(GtkWidget*) pEntryMDP);

g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(pLogBtn), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(Login), lLogMdp);
```

In the callback function :

```
void Login(GtkWidget *pLogBtn, GSList *lLogMdp)

GtkWidget *pEntryID;
GtkWidget *pEntryMDP;
const gchar *sIDEntry;
const gchar *sMDPEntry;

pEntryID = (GtkWidget*) g_slist_nth(lLogMdp, 1);
pEntryMDP = (GtkWidget*) g_slist_nth(lLogMdp, 2);
```

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgWHT.png)

Comment: `g_slist_nth()` starts counting from 0, so in `g_slist_nth(lLogMdp, 2);` you're giving it an index that is out of bounds

Comment: Also note that `g_slist_nth()` returns the `GSList`, NOT the content itself, so you should be using `g_slist_nth_data()`

Comment: I think that [g_object_set_data](https://youtu.be/9xRU7Y5rrW4) is enough for that.

Comment: To pass on a closure, you should be using the user_data argument, as that’s what it’s for. Using g_object_set_data() is just a workaround (also: please don’t use it as a quick way to post your videos)

Comment: Nielsdg i were thinking that the first element of the GSlist is the pointer that i create first (for me lLogMdp)